# Replace S00 with SOO using regular expression

Tags: regex, string

I have a scenario like whenever i get a string like S00 B00 replace with SOO BOO i mean replace zero's with O's. I have written the reg ex as    standardName.replaceAll("[A-Z][00]","OO" ) . But this is also removing the character S or B, i am getting only OO. I need output as SOO BOO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the letter and use a back-reference:

```
standardName = standardName.replaceAll("([A-Z])00","$1OO" );
```

Or even safer with word boundaries:

```
standardName = standardName.replaceAll("\\b([A-Z])00\\b","$1OO" );
```

Or using lookbehind:

```
standardName = standardName.replaceAll("\\b(?<=[A-Z])00\\b","OO" );
```

Comment: I have another string for eg DEV0N, i should Convert embedded zeros to “O”s in cases where letters are immediately adjacent on both sides of the zero, i should get the output as DEVON

Comment: You can use: `standardName.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])0(?=[A-Z])","O" );`

Comment: Hey one more please 0LLie should be replaced to OLLIE , one zero followed by any characters, i tried with something but that's not working now.

Comment: ok try: `standardName.replaceAll("(?<=[A-Z])0|0(?=[A-Z])","O" );`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72665/discussion-between-shaik-mujahid-ali-and-anubhava).